# Nginx proxy_pass with variable - full path

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Originally I had a conf like this:

```
location /some/path/ {
  proxy_pass       http://other.host/foo/;
}
```

And requests to `http://my.domain/some/path/bar` would be proxied to `http://other.host/foo/bar`

I started using variables in the proxy_pass to force nginx to re-resolve DNS:

```
location /some/path/ {
  resolver        1.2.3.4;
  set $proxy_root  "other.host/foo"
  proxy_pass       http://$proxy_root/;
}
```

But I found that the remainder of the uri path was no longer being appended, so now requests to `http://my.domain/some/path/bar` would be proxied to simply `http://other.host/foo/`.

So I changed it to a regex

```
location ~ ^/some/path/(.*) {
  resolver        1.2.3.4;
  set $proxy_root  "other.host/foo"
  proxy_pass       http://$proxy_root/$1;
}
```

But that doesn't include any query parameters, so I updated again

```
location ~ ^/some/path/(.*) {
  resolver        1.2.3.4;
  set $proxy_root  "other.host/foo"
  proxy_pass       http://$proxy_root/$1?$args;
}
```

This kinda works, but it means there's a ? in *every* target address, when only some of the incoming requests actually have a ?query section...

I think I could do some further string manipulation, but this feels like a bit much. Is there a simpler way to proxy_pass as I did originally, but with the proxy target as a variable to force re-resolution?

Comment: Use `$is_args` variable instead of hardcoded `?`

Comment: I've been fighting with similar problem for days, please have a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/638505/nginx-dynamic-proxy-pass-doesnt-resolve-properly 
It may help you

Comment: I've fixed 'resolover' to 'resolver', just in case somebody cuts and pastes your code :)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of working with the location matcher, another option is to use `$request_uri` and match the part you want to maintain. `$request_uri` contains the full URI including query parameters (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri).

Since the `location` block matches `/some/path/`, use a regular expression to obtain the remainder:

```
  if ($request_uri ~* "/some/path(/.*$)")
      set  $path_remainder  $1;
  }
```

Finally, concatenate the remainder:

```
location /some/path/ {
  resolver        1.2.3.4;
  set $proxy_root  "other.host/foo";
  if ($request_uri ~* "/some/path(/.*$)") {
      set  $path_remainder  $1;
  }
  proxy_pass       http://$proxy_root$path_remainder;
}
```

As for why this happens, according to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass :

> In some cases, the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be
>   determined

with one of those cases being

> When variables are used in proxy_pass:
>
> ```
> location /name/ {
>     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1$request_uri; 
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, if URI is specified in the directive, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original request URI.

This is the case here since you have $proxy_root in your proxy_pass directive parameter.

Comment: Be careful with this rex exp matches are unescaped so a space will cause issues